# Why didn't the Eight Tails' horns grow back?

Tags: naruto

From [**Eight Tails**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Gy%C5%ABki) article:

> The lower left part of its horns was **permanently sliced off** in a battle with A, and the right horns were **destroyed** by its own point-blank Tailed Beast Ball when fighting the Ten-Tails.
>
> Instead of hind-legs, its lower half consists of its eight tails, which resemble the cephalopod arms of an octopus. **These tails will grow back in the event they are sliced off.**

If the tails are able to **grow back**, then why can't the horns too? Since Gyūki is made of chakra, how was it possible to *permanently slice off* a part of its horns?

Comment: Because Kishimoto thought that it makes Hachibi wilder that way...maybe.

Comment: @SakuraiTomoko maybe. But still doesnt explain the logic.

Comment: Hmm, a pretty interesting question. My guess is that a tailed beasts head is  its weakness and any damage made to that region probably never heals. I have no source to back it up thou lol

Comment: @TheAnimeScientist I've thought so too. But I'm looking for a canon answer, and can't find the reason anywhere on my own.

Answer (score 2):

It comes down to the basic fundamentals.

The bottom half of the 8 Tailed Beast is an octopus, but the top is more bull like.

Bulls horns are like bone, unlike tentacles made of easily dividable cells, the horns of an animal do not "grow from the top but from the bottom upwards" they are like finger nails, the horns may eventually "grow" but not "heal".

Comment: Nice answer . But the thing is the top and bottom aren't actual halves of a bull or octopus. Pure chakra. If they were actual halves , your answer is perfect. Also , the wiki says it was *permanently sliced off* ie it wont *grow* back.

Answer (score 0):

Orochimaru had cultivated the cells of the Eight-Tails' horn, which grew into the piece that was cut off by Killer A. That horn had some of the Eight-Tails chakra. The Eight-Tails cannot grow the horn because it is made of chakra and the chakra comprising the horn was in a cultivated horn of the Eight-Tails. It can't just grow it back and create chakra out of nowhere. That violates the Law of Conservation of Energy. It's just common sense. You can't get something out of nothing. The Eight-Tails' tails regrow because the original tails decayed when cut off from the main body and released the chakra which reaccumulated in the main body so the tails could grow back. The horn did not grow back because the chakra released from the horn which was cut off from the main body and later decayed had reaccumulated in the horn cultured by Orochimaru. My source is Naruto Shippuden Season 14 Episode 318 "A Hole in the Heart: The Other Jinchuriki".

Comment: Do you possibly have any sources for this answer?

Comment: Orochimaru had harvested the Eight Tails' chakra to get Blue B's DNA. And not to get a new piece of the horn. Plus, the *Naruto* universe doesn't have our laws of physics as base. So I have to disagree with your answer.

Comment: Dear @Ero Sɘnnin , He had MANY other methods to get Blue B's DNA (When he gave him the gen-jutsu medication, from his corpse, etc). Plus, the Law of Conversion of Energy is common sense and the horn serves as a store of the Eight-Tails chakra.

Comment: Dear @SWard , you can simply watch the episodes and understand that.

Comment: 1) The law of conversion of energy *doesn't* apply to Naruto universe. Common sense comes into play when you realize that. If Gyuuki does have that attribute, why do the tails regrow? According to your answer, the tails shouldn't be able to regrow. But surprise.

Comment: 2) @SWard was asking you to cite the sources from which you derived your answer (which manga chapter or anime episode)

Comment: Ans of 1) @EroSɘnnin , the Eight-Tails' tails regrow  because the original tails decayed when cut off from the main body and released the chakra which reaccumulated in the main body so the tails could grow back. The horn did not grow back because the chakra released from the horn which was cut off from the main body and later decayed had reaccumulated in the horn cultured by Orochimaru. The law of conservation of energy never needed to be a law. It's just common sense. You can't get something out of nothing.

Comment: Ans of 2) @EroSɘnnin , My exact source is Naruto Shippuden Season 14 Episode 318 "A Hole in the Heart: The Other Jinchuriki".

Comment: Had you explained all that in your answer above, it would be more feasible.

Comment: @EroSɘnnin , I edited it.